# Why css-loader/test.rule/css.file extension have to put i after Regexp?

Tags: webpack

I'm new to learn Webpack using CSS loader, and I don't get it why rule.test have put i after Regexp? like this /.css$/i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i` is a [regex modifier](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp) to allow for case-insensitive match.